# why the style of navigation bar on wordpress wont apply?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I used a responsive navigation bar from Bootstrap:

```
       <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">

            <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>

            <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Item 2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

but when I add this wordpress php function :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Menu')); ?>
```

instead of all the "li" tags to pull the nav items dynamically, the style of the navigation bar disappears.
It works to put this php in a simple "nav" tag with "li" tags and stuff but in this html it doesn't...
What should I do to solve this problem? I want the navigation to be responsive, did I use the bootstrap code wrongly or what? Please help
UPDATE: remember that everything works I mean php retrieves the navs item, the only problem is that there's no style...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap and Wordpress menus don't work together out of the box. In order to integrate the two, I suggest using **wp-bootstrap-navwalker**: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker